# SEO Ajax and Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, seo

I'm messing a little about how to allow Google to index Ajax content.

I would like to clarify my ideas posting here until i understood:

- Apparently we have to provide to google a "pretty" url to index like /content/contentdetail#!id=0123456.
- For other hand we have to serve Html fragments for this pretty urls instead complete pages.
- We have to put in the page a tag to indicate to google that we will use this pretty urls: `<meta name="fragment" content="!">`

Could you explain me how it works? its only client javascript programming what i should do to implement it, or server too? I have to create a route for handle this types of urls?

I have the feeling that I'm messing too much.

Comment: Do you have a compelling reason for `#!` stuff or just to follow a trend?

Comment: +1 on @Antons comment. Using "Hashbanging" is really not a user friendly way of displaying URLS. I simply can't understand why the Url couldn't be /content/detail/0123456 instead, which is the entirety of the MVC routing.

Answer (score 1):

on dealing with this stuff we have always created none javascript enabled versions of pages this covers for Javascript being disabled and also for all search engines too rather than just working towards google.  also no matter what changes with search engines we dont have to change our code or how the site works because we dident make it for a search engine, we make the site for users without javascript.

also with SEO it is not important that google see's your content, what is important is that the content changes  always and is relevant, if you can make it change then google will love you because it is a data hungry monster that just wants feeding and feeding.

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Google put together thorough to walk you through the process step by step

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

Did you try following their instructions?